# Explaining Weird Behavior of Function

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the following function which is a $C^{\infty}$ function.
$$ f(t) = \begin{cases} 
       0 & t \leq 0 \\
      e^{-1/t} & t > 0 
   \end{cases}
$$

We can check that the taylor series at $0$ of $f$ is identically zero because all of its derivatives are of the form $\frac{e^{-1/t}}{t^n}$ which go to $0$ as $t \rightarrow 0$. However, we can check that 
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}\  f(t) = 1.$$

My question is how does $f$ even get "started" from $0$ if all of its derivatives are $0$?

Comment: It gets started, it just gets started slower than any polynomial $t^n$, in _exactly_ the same way that $e^t$ (eventually) grows faster than any polynomial $t^n$. Also note that $C^\infty$ does not in general mean "Taylor expandable". That would be what is usually called "analytic", and it is a whole lot more restrictive.

Comment: @Arthur: yes it's not Taylor expandable. Also please explain your answer in a rigorous way if possible.

Comment: The wording is a bit unlucky. The function has a Taylor expansion, alas it does not coincide with it.

Comment: To get a rigorous answer to "how does it get started" you'll probably need to give a rigorous definition of "get started".

Comment: @SandeepSilwal - Arthur means that if $P$ is any polynomial with $P(0) = 0$ and $P(t) > 0$ for $t \in (0,\delta)$ for some $\delta > 0$, then there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $0 < f(t) < P(t)$ on $(0,\epsilon)$

Comment: This is an example of a $C^{\infty}$ real function which cannot be extended to an analytic function on $\mathcal C$.

Answer (score 0):

The derivatives $\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{t}}}{t^n}$ tends to $0$ as $t\rightarrow 0^+$, while as $t\rightarrow 0^-$ it tends to $\infty$.

A more reasonable example is $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
e^{-\frac{1}{1-|t|^2}},  & \text{$|t|\leq 1$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{$|t|\gt1$}
\end{cases}$$